ifelse statement to setup a constraint
I have two dataframes with two columns df1$Credits and df2$Credits.
I want to construct an ifelse statement that if df2$Credits is lower than df1$Credits than it automatically defaults to df1$Credits.
So far I have something like this
ifelse(df2$CreditTY < df1$CreditTY, df2$CreditTY <- df1$CreditTY, df2$CreditTY)
Would something like this work?
I tried using the above ifelse statement but it seems to default to the lower version

you can use numpy.where() function.
Assuming that df1 is the dataframe you are trying to edit:
import numpy as np

#syntax
#np.where(condition, true, false)

df1['Credits'] = np.where(df1['Credits'].gt(df2['Credits]), df1['Credits'], df2['Credits'])

